# fabric get - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 44: ordinal not in range

Tags: python, fabric

Python Version 3.6
Fabric 2.6.0
RHEL 7

I have the same script that runs fine on one server, but fails on another server with error ('ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 44: ordinal not in range(128))

```
from fabric import *

c = Connection(host=destHost, user=userid, connect_kwargs={'password': userpw})
res = c.get("/tmp/test.txt", "current.test.txt", preserve_mode=True)
```

locale look's identical on both the servers. locale on the host where it works

```
#locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

locale on the host where it's failing

```
locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

trace logs

```
2021-09-21 07:00:05,317:INFO    :myFunctions:remoteFileChkSum:61 remoteFileChkSum: dest_hostxxx:fnma_ip_hostname.json connecting to dest_hostxxx
2021-09-21 07:00:05,317:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /etc/invoke.yaml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,317:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /etc/invoke.yml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /etc/invoke.json, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /appl/johnx/.invoke.yaml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /appl/johnx/.invoke.yml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /appl/johnx/.invoke.json, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:941 Merging config sources in order onto new empty _config...
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:943 Defaults: {'run': {'asynchronous': False, 'disown': False, 'dry': False, 'echo': False, 'echo_stdin': None, 'encoding': None, 'env': {}, 'err_stream': None, 'fallback': True, 'hide': None, 'in_stream': None, 'out_stream': None, 'pty': False, 'replace_env': False, 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'warn': False, 'watchers': []}, 'runners': {'local': <class 'invoke.runners.Local'>}, 'sudo': {'password': None, 'prompt': '[sudo] password: ', 'user': None}, 'tasks': {'auto_dash_names': True, 'collection_name': 'tasks', 'dedupe': True, 'executor_class': None, 'search_root': None}, 'timeouts': {'command': None}}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:945 Collection-driven: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:971 System-wide config file (/etc/invoke.py): {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:971 Per-user config file (/appl/johnx/.invoke.py): {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:968 Per-project config file has not been loaded yet, skipping
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:950 Environment variable config: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:968 Runtime config file has not been loaded yet, skipping
2021-09-21 07:00:05,318:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:953 Overrides: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:955 Modifications: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:957 Deletions: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /etc/fabric.yaml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /etc/fabric.yml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /etc/fabric.json, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /appl/johnx/.fabric.yaml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /appl/johnx/.fabric.yml, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:_load_file:896 Didn't see any /appl/johnx/.fabric.json, skipping.
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:941 Merging config sources in order onto new empty _config...
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:943 Defaults: {'run': {'asynchronous': False, 'disown': False, 'dry': False, 'echo': False, 'echo_stdin': None, 'encoding': None, 'env': {}, 'err_stream': None, 'fallback': True, 'hide': None, 'in_stream': None, 'out_stream': None, 'pty': False, 'replace_env': True, 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'warn': False, 'watchers': []}, 'runners': {'local': <class 'invoke.runners.Local'>, 'remote': <class 'fabric.runners.Remote'>}, 'sudo': {'password': None, 'prompt': '[sudo] password: ', 'user': None}, 'tasks': {'auto_dash_names': True, 'collection_name': 'fabfile', 'dedupe': True, 'executor_class': None, 'search_root': None}, 'timeouts': {'command': None, 'connect': None}, 'connect_kwargs': {}, 'forward_agent': False, 'gateway': None, 'inline_ssh_env': False, 'load_ssh_configs': True, 'port': 22, 'ssh_config_path': None, 'user': 'johnx'}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,319:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:945 Collection-driven: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:971 System-wide config file (/etc/fabric.py): {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:971 Per-user config file (/appl/johnx/.fabric.py): {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:968 Per-project config file has not been loaded yet, skipping
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:950 Environment variable config: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:968 Runtime config file has not been loaded yet, skipping
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:953 Overrides: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:955 Modifications: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:957 Deletions: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :fabric:_load_ssh_file:273 File not found, skipping
2021-09-21 07:00:05,320:DEBUG   :fabric:_load_ssh_file:271 Loaded 2 new ssh_config rules from '/etc/ssh/ssh_config'
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:941 Merging config sources in order onto new empty _config...
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:943 Defaults: {'run': {'asynchronous': False, 'disown': False, 'dry': False, 'echo': False, 'echo_stdin': None, 'encoding': None, 'env': {}, 'err_stream': None, 'fallback': True, 'hide': None, 'in_stream': None, 'out_stream': None, 'pty': False, 'replace_env': True, 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'warn': False, 'watchers': []}, 'runners': {'local': <class 'invoke.runners.Local'>, 'remote': <class 'fabric.runners.Remote'>}, 'sudo': {'password': None, 'prompt': '[sudo] password: ', 'user': None}, 'tasks': {'auto_dash_names': True, 'collection_name': 'fabfile', 'dedupe': True, 'executor_class': None, 'search_root': None}, 'timeouts': {'command': None, 'connect': None}, 'connect_kwargs': {}, 'forward_agent': False, 'gateway': None, 'inline_ssh_env': False, 'load_ssh_configs': True, 'port': 22, 'ssh_config_path': None, 'user': 'johnx'}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:945 Collection-driven: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:971 System-wide config file (/etc/fabric.py): {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:971 Per-user config file (/appl/johnx/.fabric.py): {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:968 Per-project config file has not been loaded yet, skipping
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:950 Environment variable config: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:_merge_file:968 Runtime config file has not been loaded yet, skipping
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:953 Overrides: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:955 Modifications: {'inline_ssh_env': False}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,322:DEBUG   :invoke:merge:957 Deletions: {}
2021-09-21 07:00:05,323:INFO    :myFunctions:remoteFileChkSum:64 remoteFileChkSum: dest_hostxxx:fnma_ip_hostname.json getting /export/apps/moogsoft/config/data/fnma_ip_hostname.json
2021-09-21 07:00:05,324:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 starting thread (client mode): 0xc9dcf358
2021-09-21 07:00:05,324:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
2021-09-21 07:00:05,344:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2021-09-21 07:00:05,345:INFO    :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.4)
2021-09-21 07:00:05,350:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 kex algos:['gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==', 'gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==', 'gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==', 'curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519'] client encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', '3des-cbc'] server encrypt:['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', '3des-cbc'] client mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] server mac:['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
2021-09-21 07:00:05,351:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
2021-09-21 07:00:05,351:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
2021-09-21 07:00:05,351:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
2021-09-21 07:00:05,351:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
2021-09-21 07:00:05,351:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Compression agreed: none
2021-09-21 07:00:05,360:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
2021-09-21 07:00:05,361:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Switch to new keys ...
2021-09-21 07:00:05,361:DEBUG   :paramiko.transport:_log:1819 Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for dest_hostxxx: b'96d89556857014c8f0e4cc41ab271031'
2021-09-21 07:00:05,362:ERROR   :myFunctions:remoteFileChkSum:71 remoteFileChkSum: dest_hostxxx:fnma_ip_hostname.json'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)
2021-09-21 07:00:05,362:ERROR   :__main__:main:176 Unable to download current file from dest_hostxxx ...Aborting transfer of file. Send Email
```

My code

```
def remoteFileChkSum(filename, destHost, userid, userpw, destDir):
    fnName = "remoteFileChkSum: " + destHost + ":" + filename

    try:
        logger.info(fnName + " connecting to " + destHost)
        c = Connection(host=destHost, user=userid, connect_kwargs={'password': userpw})
        tmpFileName = "/tmp/" + destHost + "." + filename
        logger.info(fnName + " getting " + destDir + "/" + filename)
        res = c.get(destDir + "/" + filename, tmpFileName, preserve_mode=True)
        logger.info(fnName + " downloaded " + destDir + "/" + filename + " to /tmp/")
        return {'status': True, 'chksum': fileChkSum, 'details': ''}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(fnName + str(e))
        return {'status': False, 'details': str(e)}
```

full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 777, in get
    return Transfer(self).get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/transfer.py", line 128, in get
    self.sftp.getcwd() or self.sftp.normalize("."), remote
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/transfer.py", line 38, in sftp
    return self.connection.sftp()
  File "<decorator-gen-5>", line 2, in sftp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 29, in opens
    self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 636, in open
    self.client.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 735, in _auth
    filename, pkey_class, passphrase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 586, in _key_from_filepath
    key = klass.from_private_key_file(key_path, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 235, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 175, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 308, in _read_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 312, in _read_private_key
    lines = f.readlines()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 44: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Strange. Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @tdelaney updated the post with logs and the code

Comment: Puzzling. There is a log from line 64 then it seems like the log from line 71 failss. By my count, that's the line after the code shown. Of course it may be the log in the exception, but check what's on 71. Maybe the log file is open "ascii"? See what `sys.stdout.encoding`, `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` and `locale.getpreferredencoding()` say.

Comment: Just found out, I am able to run the script on that server with other users. But just one user has issues. The locale output for both users look identical. I remove the users .bashrc file, logged back in, now I see a different error. `utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 44: invalid start byte`

Comment: Update question with traceback

Comment: That's in paramiko's code to read the private key file. On a linux system, the defaults are in ~/.ssh but they can be configured through paramiko or fabric. The files in .ssh should be ascii with hex encodings of the key. You could check those files in python with `open("hwatever", encoding='ascii').read()` or maybe even temporarily hack /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py, line 175 - put in a print of the filename just before the read.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you for pointing that out. Something to do with $HOME/.ssh/ files. Not sure which one. I removed all the files from /appl/fs7prod/.ssh and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @tdelaney. The problem was with the $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa. Removing the file resolved the issue. Look's like the paramiko code was importing something from that file.